# xmlstarlet sel concatenates two first – is it a bug, or my mistake in CLI

Tags: xpath, epub, xmlstarlet

I have tried to get in bash elements from manifest section of a [content.opf](http://idpf.org/epub/20/spec/OPF_2.0.1_draft.htm) file.

I do use
`xmlstarlet sel  -N "dc=http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" -N "opf=http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf" -t -v 'opf:package/opf:manifest/opf:item/@href' content.opf`
and get first two resulsts in the list concatenated as one element.

**Is it the bug of xmlstarlet or just my fault?**

Comment: That sounds like buggy behaviour of version 1.3.0, 1.3.1+ should print all elements newline separated, 1.2.x- would give just the first element. See [Bug #2563866](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2563866&group_id=66612&atid=515106).

Answer (score 0):

*My fault. Of course.*

Changing `-t -v 'opf:package/opf:manifest/opf:item/@href'` to `-t -m 'opf:package/opf:manifest/opf:item' -v '@href' -n` did cure the problem!

**Remind to myself – RTFM.** Any interested what for may visit [my script](https://bitbucket.org/Kacper_Perschke/epubpack).